# How do I use mongoDB Comparison Query Operator's to work with createdAt dates?

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime, meteor

I am trying to write a mongoDB query that will only yield objects that were created today.

Find below the query I feed into my Chrome browser:

```
var currentDate = Date(); 
console.log(currentDate); 
Meteor.users.find({}, {createdAt: {$gte: currentDate}} ).fetch();
```

The code above yields:

```
Mon Oct 01 2018 14:35:58 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)

(2) [{…}, {…}]

0: {_id: "REzQZdJJgjJ8q29eF", createdAt: Sat Sep 29 2018 10:48:51 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)}
1: {_id: "JzgBEtSji9aYAQws6", createdAt: Mon Oct 01 2018 10:15:48 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Note two things. The current given date is: `Mon Oct 01 2018 14:35:58 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)`, yet the query ignores the `$gte` and spits out documents that were `$lte`.

Can anyone kindly explain to me why this **Comparison Query Operator** isn't working, also kindly suggest a working solution to this query?

Looking forward to your help

Comment: it's `find(criteria, options)` not the other way around?

Comment: @Geoffroy I thought your solution was a little unorthodox, but I went ahead and gave it a go anyway. I hope this is what you meant: 'Meteor.users.find({createdAt: {$lte: date}}, {} ).fetch()'; unfortunately this doesn't yield anything at all. If this isnt what you meant, kindly elaborate in code.

Comment: it was not unorthodox, as the accepted answer shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a *current datetime* variable and looking for documents that were created after it - that is almost always going to yield no documents. You need to truncate the date down to today at `00:00:00`. Also note the `new Date()` instead of just `Date()`.

```
const currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
Meteor.users.find({ createdAt: { $gte: currentDate }}).fetch();
```

Finally note that this will give you midnight in your local time zone, not zulu time.

Comment: Help I need your help with this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653385/how-do-i-use-the-mongodb-comparison-query-operator-to-check-for-values-between-c)