# How do I use the mongoDB Comparison Query Operator to check for values between createdAt dates?

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor, mongodb-query

I would like to view all the created users `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` that were created in the database between the beginning of 1st September and the end of 30th September. How do I achieve this in code.

Find inline my failed attempt:

```
var beginningOfMonth = new Date();
beginningOfMonth.setMonth(8, 1); 
console.log("beginning Of the Month: "+beginningOfMonth);
```

The code above yeilds:

```
beginning Of the Month: Sat Sep 01 2018 21:44:00 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)
```

...

```
var endOfMonth = new Date(); 
endOfMonth.setMonth(8, 30);     
console.log("end Of the Month: "+endOfMonth);
```

The code above yields:

```
end Of the Month: Sun Sep 30 2018 21:44:00 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)
```

...perfect so far, however in the query below:

```
Meteor.users.find({ createdAt: { $gte: currentDate }}, { createdAt: { lte: endMonth }},  { "services.google.email": { $exists: true } } ).fetch();
```

The query above yields the below. NOTE that the `createAt` dates lay outside what the query queries.

```
[{…}]
 0:
  createdAt: Thu Oct 04 2018 14:54:33 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time) 
  profile: {name: "Sir ProgrammerAllot"}
  services: {google: {…}, resume: {…}}
  _id: "2trR7WxnqKJuuipG8"
  __proto__: Object
 length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

How do I modify the query to only show the users created in the database  between 1st of september and the last day of September?

Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put all your query terms into a single object (and use `$lte` instead of `lte`):

```
Meteor.users.find({
    createdAt: { $gte: currentDate, $lte: endMonth },
    "services.google.email": { $exists: true }
}).fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately your solution (though it makes allot of logical sense) does not yield anything at all.

Comment: ...elaborating on YOUR solution, I found out that wrapping every criteria helped in making the query work. Check out the answer for clarity. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the "*query terms into a single object*" as suggested by @JohnnyHK, and wrapping every query (criteria) statement helped in making the overall query work.

Find below the working solution:

```
Meteor.users.find(
       {createdAt: { $gte: beginningOfMonth, $lte: endOfMonth }}, 
       {"services.google.email": { $exists: true }}
).count();
```

Comment: You're going to have problems with these queries if you don't also properly truncate the hours of the start and finish times to midnight (UTC or local depending on your requirements). You also typically want to use a strict less than on the end date and set that date to the 1st day of next month, i.e. `{createdAt: {gte: firstDayOfMonthAt00, lt: firstDayOfFollowingMonthAt00}}` This avoids having to figure out how many days each month has.